# NH Linq with FetchMany and ToFutureValue in NH 3.0.0beta

Tags: linq, nhibernate

I'm trying to use the ToFuture with the new NH Linq 3.0 provider.

This works fine:

```
var result = ses.Query<Parent>()
                .Where(x => x.Id == id)
                .ToFutureValue();
```

but when I use a Fetch/FetchMany like this:

```
var result = ses.Query<Parent>()
                .Where(x => x.Id == id)
                .Fetch(x => X.Child)
                .ToFutureValue();
```

This exception occurs:

> NotSupportedException with: You can
>   also use the AsFuture() method on
>   NhQueryable

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not implemented yet (LINQ Futures is one of the most recently added features, just a few weeks ago).

You can enter an issue at http://jira.nhforge.org/

Answer (score 0):

.Fetch(x => X.Child) 
return IQueryable<>, not NhQueryable<>
that's why we got exception

Take a look:

http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Metadata/Default/Project/NHibernate/3.0.0.GA/Release/All/NHibernate/NHibernate/Linq/LinqExtensionMethods.cs